# Python Script adding data to wrong row

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a python script to use selenium for scraping a website. The website has 2 dropdown options for Country and Company Code or Company Name, and displays the list of documents needed after clicking the submit button.

While running the script I am having issues with the list of documents being added to the next row instead of the actual row.

Here's the script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import time

countries = ["ABC","DEF"]
companies = ["123","456"]

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Export data to CSV
with open('example.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(["Country", "Comp_ID", "Comp_N", "Evidence"])

    for country_name in countries:
        country_ini = driver.find_element(By.ID, "abc-country-container")
        country_ini.click()

        country = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "abc-country-search__field")
        country.send_keys(country_name)
        country.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        for company_code in companies:
            company_ini = driver.find_element(By.ID, "abc-company-id-container")
            company_ini.click()

            company = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "abc-company-search__field")
            company.send_keys(company_code)
            company.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

            company_name_display = driver.find_element(By.ID, "abc-company-name-container")
            company_name_text = company_name_display.text

            display = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnSubmitEvidence")
            display.click()

            driver.implicitly_wait(10)

            evidence = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-xs-8.col-sm-9.header-text")
            evidence_data = [eve.text.strip() for eve in evidence if eve.text.strip()]

            writer.writerow([country_name, company_code, company_name_text, ", ".join(evidence_data)])

            # Add a time sleep of 5 seconds between iterations
            time.sleep(5)


driver.quit()
```

The result I am expecting is

| Country | Comp_ID | Comp_N | Evidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | CompN1 | D1, D2 |
| ABC | 456 | CompN2 | D1 |
| DEF | 123 | CompN1 | D2, D3 |
| DEF | 456 | CompN2 | D3, D4 |

Instead the result I am getting is

| Country | Comp_ID | Comp_N | Evidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | CompN1 |  |
| ABC | 456 | CompN2 | D1, D2 |
| DEF | 123 | CompN1 | D1 |
| DEF | 456 | CompN2 | D2, D3 |